# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC : downloads and shows a blank page in the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datatables

I'm trying to download files from my file sharing portal. I'm using a Datatable, the download works fine on the first page but if I try to download a file from any other page the app. Download the file and showing a blank page in the browser.

This is the download method:

```
[Route("DownloadFile")]
public async Task<FileResult> DownloadFile(Guid id)
{
    var path = await getDocumentFullPath(id);
    var fileName = await getDocumentTitle(id);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        throw new Exception("Please select a file to download.");

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        throw new FileNotFoundException();

    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

    if (!provider.TryGetContentType(path, out var contenttype))
    {
        contenttype = "application/octet-stream";
    }

    var bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);

    return File(bytes, contenttype, fileName);
}
```

`.cshtml` file:

```
<table id="documents" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Document Code</th>
            <th>Extension</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a class="action-icon docTypes" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Document", new { id = item.DocumentId })'">@item.Title</a>
                </td>

                <td>@item.DocumentDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</td>
                <td>@item.DocumentCode</td>
                <td>@item.Extension</td>
                <td>
                        
                    <a asp-action="Update" asp-route-Id="@item.DocumentId" class="action-icon"> <i class="fa fa-edit m-1"></i></a>
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-Id="@item.DocumentId" class="action-icon"> <i class="fa fa-thin fa-list m-1"></i></a>
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-Id="@item.DocumentId" class="action-icon"> <i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can m-1"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        new DataTable('#documents');

        $(".docTypes").hover(function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
        });
    </script>
}
```

The project is using ASP.NET Core 7.

I tried this method first:

```
<a asp-action="DownloadFile"
      asp-controller="Document"
      asp-route-id="@item.DocumentId">
      @item.Title
</a>
```

instead of:

```
<a class="action-icon docTypes" 
   onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Document", new { id = item.DocumentId })'">@item.Title</a>
```

but unfortunately, it's not working, also I googled for this problem without any luck...

[image: in page two before click download]

[image: the file was downloaded but with blank page in the browser]

Comment: Hello, have you tried the solution provided? Do you still have any concern on this? Let me know if you need further assistance?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to download files from my file sharing portal. I'm using a
> Datatable, the download works fine on the first page but if I try to
> download a file from any other page the app. Download the file and
> showing a blank page in the browser

While calling DownloadFile controller action, did you check what are you getting here in path and fileName?. Another point is that, does File(bytes, contenttype, fileName) returned that data you are expecting? Based on your shared code, I think your front-end code has no issue, please debug your DownloadFile action in details if thats populated with correct response.

Regarding your download DOM, you can do as following:

```
<a asp-controller="DownloadAll" asp-action="DownloadFile" class="btn btn-info" asp-route-imageName="du.png">Download</a>
```

**Note:** I have used string as my parameter, as you have used GUID, please make sure that is correct and your `asp-route` contains matched value within your controller action.

Working Sample:

Controller action:

```
[Route("DownloadFile")]
public async Task<FileResult> DownloadFile(string imageName)
{
    var path = Path.GetFullPath("./wwwroot/ImageName/Cover/" + imageName);
    MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
    }
    memory.Position = 0;
    return File(memory, "image/png", Path.GetFileName(path));
}
```

Note: I have tested with image file, please make sure your relevant GUID contains correct data.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Finally, based on your scenario, I would suggest you to check the route value and the corresponding Id if that is valid and has the value related to it.

Comment: The GUID serves as the document ID. I utilize the document ID provided by the user's selection, and then I employ the "getDocumentFullPath(id)" method to compute the complete path.

I can download the files from the first page of the DataTable without any problem. The issue comes when I try to download from other pages.
Try to use DataTable with multi-pages and try to download any file from page two or next pages..

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are changing page when click download file. Its not shown in url but you are changing it. So add `download` to your `a` tag  like this.

```
 <a class="action-icon docTypes" href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Document", new { id = item.DocumentId })" download>@item.Title</a>
```

It will download file instead of navigating to the file

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but unfortunately it's not working..